# SQL multiple table query, join syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I have following:
Tables(field names)

1. Active( activeID, activeName)
2. ActiveCategories(activeID, categoryID)
3. Categories(categoryID,categoryName)

I wish to query such that the result fetches Left Join of Active on ActiveCategories but instead of CategoryID [from ActiveCategories] Integer it should display corresponding categoryName [ from Categories].
Till now I have managed to display integer but not the corresponding name.

Comment: Can you show us anything you have attempted yet?

Comment: You just need to add another `JOIN` with the `Categories` table. Why didn't this work for you?

Comment: MY ATTEMPT >>> __sql__ = "SELECT Active.*, ActiveCategories.CategoryID FROM Active LEFT JOIN ActiveCategories on Active.ActiveID=ActiveCategories.ActiveID"
[ActiveID] <<<< Don't know what to do next..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.activeID, a.activeName, c.categoryName
from Active a 
left outer join ActiveCategories b on a.activeID = b.activeID
left outer join Categories c on b.categoryID = c.categoryID
```

Comment: you might want `coalesce(c.categoryName,'Unknown') as categoryName`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

select a.activeID, a.activeName, d.categoryName

```
from Active a 
    left join (select b.activeID activeID, c.categoryName CategoryName
            from ActiveCategories b
                left join Categories c on b.categoryID = c.categoryID) d
        on a.activeID = d.activeID
```